# spring отказоустойчивость jdbc

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, jdbc

Есть две базы(PostgreSQL) дублирующие полностью друг друга.В нашем апи приложении раньше использовался один датасурс, т.к реплики никакой не было и отказоустойчивость никого не волновала, а теперь же надо переключаться между датасурсами в рантайме в зависимости от доступности того или иного датасурса.
В интернете я нашел информацию по этому поводу: например ha-jdbc http://blog.gelin.ru/2013/12/ha-jdbc.html, было актуально на 2013-2014 год.
Еще читал различную информацию по поводу @Primary и secondary датасурсов, но будут ли они переключаться автоматически...

Вопрос, какой best practices для динамического переключения датасурса в случае недоступности одного из оных? Если необходимо только ЧТЕНИЕ из таблиц.

PS в проекте используется spring-data-jpa v.2.1.1.

PSS или же возможно это вообще делается на уровне БД(какими-то технологиями postgresql), а не АПИ

Comment: Вы можете создать два дата сурса сразу, один из которых будет праймари, а второй резервный. Переключаться между ними можно при помощи Spring Retry или используя Hystrix + fallback

Answer (score -1):

Тебе XA драйвер нужен. И его соответствующим образом настраивать. Более подробно на этот вопрос уже был дан ответ [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46008251/how-to-do-distributed-transactions-xa-in-spring-and-glassfish-5)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]